# Has blocks gutenberg block multiples registers type in my Plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, block-editor

I created a plugin that contains multiple blocks and I want it to load assets only if I have one of those blocks created.

Is there any way to get all blocks registered by my plugin?

The idea with this is to use has_block passing the name of the block as a parameter, however, the has_block function will only accept a specific one and not an array

I created my own function to validate if I have my own blocks, however, I'm passing the block names in the hardcode array. Is there any way to avoid hardcode and return all blocks created by me? Something like `\WP_Block_Type_Registry::get_instance()->get_all_registered()` or similar?

**My function**

```
function cgb_has_block() {
    $blocks = [
        'cgb/block-idinheiro-blocks', 
        'cgb/block-idh-affiliates', 
        'cgb/block-idh-best-summary', 
        'cgb/block-idh-highlights'
    ];

    foreach ( $blocks as $block ) {
        if ( has_block( $block ) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Unclear what the question is, can you expand, thanks. Are you asking about `\WP_Block_Type_Registry::get_instance()->get_all_registered()` and matching it with your block-names or how to run `has_block` for multiple blocks?

Comment: @birgire, exactly. It's about ```\WP_Block_Type_Registry::get_instance()->get_all_registered()```. I updated the question

Comment: maybe match by the block's namespace?